# Eclipse "Enhanced Class Decompiler" plugin does not decompile when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler

Problem description:
Decompile works fine when viewing a class (i.e. Ctrl+Shift+T), but not when stepping into code from the debugging perspective - instead the "Class File Viewer" is opened. Version Used: Eclipse Oxygen and Enhanced Class Decompiler 3.0.0

Answer (score 66):

This will work on oxygen and later version as well:

Click on "Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations"

Change default to your for both **.class** association.

"***.class**" : "Class Decompiler Viewer" is selected by default.

"***.class without source**" : "Class Decompiler Viewer" is selected by default.

[image]

Answer (score 42):

This is how it should look at the beginning – at least in my case this did not allow me to decompile directly from the suspended threads view.
  [image: Decompiler Viewer is default, but will still not show the decompiled class]

1)  Add „Java Editor“ (Probably any other would do as well) at make it default. Of course this does not work, but the idea is to trigger a config change again
[image: Setting (nonsense) "Java Editor" to trigger the change of editor to be registered]

2)  Set Class Decompiler viewer as Default again – now it should be possible to view the decompiled class directly from suspended threads.

Comment: This did not EXACTLY work for me.  Instead, I had to do the same thing under the "class without source" file type.

Comment: The method of @matt forsythe above worked perfectly for me in Photon.

Comment: I did this and still get "source not found" while debugging, I had to click on "Edit Source Lookup Path" (or go to debug configuration>sources) and then "Restore defaults". Now it works as expected.