# Source not found when debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jar

My java project references many external jar files and I need debug into these jar files. But I have no source codes of these jar files.

I have installed a decompiler named Enhanced Class Decompiler 3.1.0 which found in Eclipse Marketplace.

> Enhanced Class Decompiler integrates JD, Jad, FernFlower, CFR, Procyon seamlessly with Eclipse and allows Java developers to debug class files without source code directly.

I can decompile a class file with JD-core which in the external jar file and toggle a break point successfully. But it still told me "Source not found" during debugging.

How can I debug a class file without source code directly?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396661/eclipse-enhanced-class-decompiler-plugin-does-not-decompile-when-debugging)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I have set associated editors as Class Decompiler Viewer as default both of *.class and *.class without source. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @NicholasK I have seen that question before, it can't solve my problem.

Comment: @NicholasK I tried many times follow the answer by Douglas Frari of [Eclipse java debugging: source not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found), and finally solved the problem. I should add a Archive but not a External Archive, and must Restart Eclipse after add first jar file.

Comment: @NicholasK Thanks for you advice.